# Return top 5 values with criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Return top 5 values with criteria in Excel:

1. Mark "Y" in new column (i.e. column 4 ) if the record is in Top five value in column 3 grouped by column 1 and column 2
2. Mark the corresponding order in new column (i.e. column 5)

[image: data]

Excel version: Microsoft 365 MSO (version 2212 Build 16.0.15928.20278) 64-bit

Comment: The formula work! Just wonder if you could provide formula to get the order for the record! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You'll want to respond to his answer, not your question ;)

Comment: @GaryC In case of rank number what about duplicate values? You have 4 two time for first 5 records?

Comment: Please put your sample data in [Table Markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) format. Copy the excel data, generate it, and copy it back to your question leaving a blank line. It helps to reproduce it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to the following formula-

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(C2,TAKE(SORT(FILTER($C$2:$C$50000,($A$2:$A$50000=A2)*($B$2:$B$50000=B2)),1,-1),5))),"Y","")
```

[image]